# Geocoder is returning address nowhere near me

Tags: java, android, location, locationmanager, google-geocoder

I am using LocationManager, Location, along with Geocoder to attempt to find the address of a business using the `getFromLocationName()` method.

The problem is when I print the returned address, it is nowhere near my location.  I have tried turning GPS on and wifi off to get different results, but everything remains the same. It is important to note that I am using the LocationManager to return the best provider.

Also it is important to note that I do get my exact location when I use `getFromLocation()`. The problem here is that I can not specify a business name to get its address.

```
package restaurantcheckin.pkg;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import restaurantcheckin.pkg.RowItem0;

public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
    Geocoder ugeo;
    List<Address> adr;

    LocationManager lm;
    Location ulo;

    final double range = 1.00;

    String lName;
    String stre;
    String city;
    String state;
    String zip;
    String adrOut;
    String lat;
    String lon;
    String bp;

    Criteria cri;
    Context context;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)  
    {   
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        TextView tView0 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tView);
        this.context = this;
        cri = new Criteria();
        lName = "Pizza Hut";
        lm = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        bp = lm.getBestProvider(cri,false);
        Log.d("Debug",bp);
        ulo = lm.getLastKnownLocation(bp);

        if(ulo == null)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Location not found...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                ugeo = new Geocoder(context);

                adr = ugeo.getFromLocationName(lName, 1, ulo.getLatitude() - range, ulo.getLongitude(), ulo.getLatitude(), ulo.getLongitude() - range);
                Log.d("Debug","Latit" + ulo.getLatitude() + "Long" + ulo.getLongitude());
                stre = adr.get(0).getThoroughfare();
                Log.d("Debug","stre");
                city = adr.get(0).getLocality();
                Log.d("Debug","city");
                state = adr.get(0).getAdminArea();
                Log.d("Debug","state");
                zip = adr.get(0).getPostalCode();
                Log.d("Debug","zip");

                adrOut = stre + "\n" + city + ", " + state + " " + zip;

                Log.d("Debug","adrOut");
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Log.d("Exception","Line 68");
            }
        }

        tView0.setText(adrOut);
        Log.d("Debug","setText");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
    {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

If anyone can help, please make a suggestion.  Thank you.

Comment: Is it giving you the location of a Pizza Hut? Have you checked what the returned address actually is?